# How can Erlang C values be greater than one?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, telecommunications

Here is an Erlang C plot I did myself. The x-axis represents the total traffic while the y-axis represents the probability. Each line represents a different total number of channels.

[image]

As you can see, the graph has **probabilities** greater than one. How can this be even possible?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not sure if this belongs on electrical engineering. It's likely I just don't understand _why_ it is, however.

Comment: It is related to the fundamentals of mobile communication. Do you know a better SE for this topic?

Comment: Probability of what? What is *A*? Does it make physical sense to have A > c?

Comment: Probabilities are [0, 1] _by definition_. You are misinterpreting something.

Comment: @ThePhoton 'A' is the total traffic. Whereas 'C' is the total no. of channels. Yes, it makes perfect sense and is, in fact, a real-world case. The number of subscribers can outweigh the total no. of available channels for a telecommunication system.

Comment: What event is P the probability of?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what event \$P\$ measures the probability of.

But you'll notice that your formula gives \$P>1\$ when \$A>c\$.

So I'll guess \$P\$ is something like the probability of a collision on the network, or that a particular channel is occupied with other traffic when a subscriber attempts to connect, or something like that.

Then it would make sense that \$P=1\$ when \$A>c\$ and the actual formula should be

$$P=\begin{cases}
{\rm your\ long\ formula}, & 0 < A < c \\
1, & A \ge c
\end{cases}.$$

Then the formula you used in your program doesn't represent the correct formula for \$P\$ for all choices of \$A\$ and \$c\$.